# Easiest way to append new parameters to current URL in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web, url

When navigating from menu I get route which looks similar to this

`www.address.com/verification/tasks`

and the view under this URI contains table, which has active routing so for that purpose in URL there are 2 parameters: page, limit

`www.address.com/verification/tasks/{page}/{limit}`

where page or limit is changed after doing some operations on view such as chaning pagination, filters etc.

I need those params( page&limit ) to be set onInit if URL doesn't contains them yet, so I done this that way:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const route = this.route.snapshot;

    if (!route.params.page || !route.params.limit) {
      this.router.navigate([
               '/verification/tasks',
               (route.params.page ? route.params.page : 1),
               (route.params.limit ? route.params.limit : 10)
                ])
        .then(()=>{
          this.loadFiltersData();
        })} else {
          this.loadFiltersData();
        }
    
}
```

as `route.url[0]` was only route.url entry and `route.url[0].path` was returning `tasks` without previous `verification` i had to hardcode that and don't feel thats the way it should be done.

Comment: how do you navigate to /tasks ? through any menu item ?

Comment: @micronyks ye, though menu item i navigate to /verification/tasks

Comment: then just  use `/verification/tasks/1/10` directly there rather than setting it in `ngOnInIt`

Comment: @micronyks for me its also not a perfect solutions, as you have navigation from other views so in each place you have to change that, and there is possibility that some users has saved this URL,